# refresh user control inside multiview

Tags: .net, gridview, controls, objectdatasource

In my parentpage I have dropdownlist, multiview and button. Multiview has a user control.

On click of the button i pass the selected value from dropdown to the user control and call the databind method to populate the user control with corresponding data.

User control has gridview which is populated using objectDataSource. I'm using the ObjectCreating (ObjectDataSource) to set the objectInstance.

1st time everything works fine. But when the dropdown selection is changed and the button is clicked again then the user control does not refresh. What do I need to do so that the user control refreshed each time the drop down selection is changed.

All the help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by first removing the user control from view on button click and then calling the DataBind method

Thanks